# TableView Cells not showing up after search

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

After searching, I have an array with new data. **I have confirmed this with print debugging**

Then when it runs cellForRowAtIndexRow, my custom cell doesn't init. So I added an if statement to check if my cell is nil, and if it is reinitialize it. However, when the cell is returned, it doesn't update on my view controller.

When I print **cell.cellLabel.text** after my search, it is nil. This is most likely the reason why it isn't updating, even though I have confirmed that there is data in **direntry**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Demo"];


static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"peopleCell";
PeopleCell *cell = (PeopleCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil){
    cell = (PeopleCell *)[[PeopleCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

DirEntryItem *direntry;
if(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView){
    direntry = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}else{
    direntry = [self.peopleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}


cell.name = direntry.fullname;
cell.phoneNum = direntry.phoneNum;
cell.email = direntry.email;
cell.admin = direntry.admin;
cell.cellLabel.text = direntry.fullname;

[cell.profile setImage:myImage];

return cell;
}
```

Comment: Provide the code for "PeopleCell.m"

Comment: Set a breakpoint after your statement "cell.cellLabel.text = direntry.fullname;". If direntry.fullname is not nil, cell.cellLabel.text can also not be nil.